# Apple Remote Desktop - Reports Battery Percentage or Battery Hrs Left

Tags: battery, apple-remote-desktop

With Apple Remote Desktop, how can I generate a Battery Status Hrs Left or Battery Percentage Left on my Mac Laptop(s)?

I did find something that tells me the "Battery Charge Remaining (mAh)", but it give me a number that I do not understand, example: 646.

Can I have the percentage left instead or hours will be fine too?

Thank you so much and have a wonderful day.

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

The "Battery Charge Remaining (mAh)" field in Apple Remote Desktop's Reports function indicates the remaining milliamp hours of the battery.

To find the battery percentage, you can use "Send UNIX Command" to remotely execute the following command:

```
pmset -g batt
```

The output is the percentage and status of the battery, including the estimated time until it will be fully discharged, for example:

```
51%; discharging; 3:24 remaining present: true
```